# Why I can't use “enough” in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

In this sentence: "There isn't ***much*** information yet for us to make a final decision.", could I use "enough" instead of "much"?

I think that if I use the word "enough", it is not going to change the meaning of the sentence, is it?

Could somebody please explain the difference between two here?

Comment: In fact, *enough* is preferable in that sentence.

Answer (score 3):

"There isn't enough information yet for us to make a final decision" sounds completely natural and would be fine in this sentence.

The usual meaning would be "We have some information, but need more in order to decide." I think this is what you were trying to say. However, be careful: this sort of sentence is often used as a "soft rejection" or an excuse to avoid giving an unfavorable decision.

As a native speaker, I think your original sentence sounds awkward. It's combining two thoughts: 1) We do not yet have much information (judging the "amount" of information) and 2) The information we have is not sufficient (a yes-or-no judgment: do we have all the data we need?). It's a little unusual to combine those two ways of thinking about information in one thought. So while "There isn't much information yet" is fine, your full sentence sounds weird.

Answer (score 1):

I think "enough" actually works better in your example.  Though the meaning is obvious, using "much" makes it sound a little awkward and not like a native speaker.

If you were to use only the first part, then "There isn't much information yet" would work well.

You could think of "enough" as meaning "the correct amount." "Enough" really needs something to go with it.  It's a correct amount for something... Enough food to eat, enough information to make a decision, enough medicine to cure. You can often leave out the other thing and people know what you mean by context: "I have enough food" is perfectly reasonable as food is usually for eating.

"Much," on the other hand, does not require anything else. If you have much information, then you have more than a little. "There isn't much information yet" is valid on its own. The reader (or listener) doesn't even have to know there is a decision to be made for that to makes sense.

I'm having a hard time explaining it. This example might illustrate the difference:

> There isn't much information on that new game yet, but there is enough information
>   leaked to know it looks interesting.